# ActionText gif attachment converts to photo when submitting rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, actiontext

So I've been trying to fix this for a while now and I've had no luck in doing so. I have a model Posts that has_rich_text: body

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
  has_rich_text :body
  has_rich_text :health_check
  has_one_attached :cover_photo
  has_many :post_tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :post_tags

  after_commit :add_default_cover, on: [:create, :update]

  def add_default_cover
    unless cover_photo.attached?
      self.cover_photo.attach(io: File.open(Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "default.png")), filename: 'default.png' , content_type: "image/png")
    end
  end
end
```

It works perfectly when I attach photos, but when ever I attach a gif it gets uploaded correctly into the edit/new screen and I can see the animation of the gif in the rich text editor. But as soon as I submit the edit/new form then a new variant is created as an image and that's what is being used when showing the post. When I check my storage system I find both the image and the gif versions.

Does anyone know why this is happening on submitting the form? I would want to upload a gif and display it without active stroage or action text changing it.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue. I ended up hacking it on the [client-side with JS](https://github.com/ajessee/BigDumbWebDev/blob/master/app/javascript/application/posts.js#L200).

My approach: on 'DOMContentLoaded' event for the page with the GIF/MP4s, I grab all the action text attachments, get their URLS, and then for the GIFs I replace the static image URL with the GIF URL, and for the MP4s I just create a new `<video>` element and give it the MP4 URL. It's not pretty, but it works.

Here is an [example on my blog](https://www.bigdumbweb.dev/posts/building-an-auto-save-feature-for-my-blog). Let me know if you find a better answer, this feels like something that should be built into action storage/text.

Comment: I'm really surprised there isn't a lot more discussion about this, and your answer had no upvotes.

Comment: @BasharAbdullah I think most people are waiting for the Rails/Action Text team to make additional improvements. There is a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35218#issuecomment-647315522) where there is a discussion about ActionText attachments.

Comment: @AndréJessee based on the Rails/Basecamp's attitude I think we'll be waiting a long time for meaningful improvements. I've moved on to a different WYSIWYG library.

Comment: @yakattack what did you move to?